# C# Check if a string is a Sentence

Tags: c#, filtering

Basically I want to check if a String is a Sentence ("Hello, I am Me!") or Symbol Spam ("HH,,,{''{"), without using the number of symbols as a factor as much as possible. Right now it just detects based on a counter of symbols, but when someone says something with lots of punctuation, they get kicked.

Help?

Comment: So basically you want a spam detection?

Comment: `Basically I want to check if a String is a Sentence` define the *sentence*. If you can do it, it is easy to write the code.

Comment: How about using RegEx class to validate your string.

Comment: Defining a sentance would be hard, since it's twitch :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of symbols in the text is not sufficient, and you don't want to use something too fancy (or bought) could I suggest implementing one or more of these further steps (of increasing difficulty):

1. Make a count of all A-Za-z and space characters in the string and make a ratio of this to the count of symbols - so if they write a sentence then !!!!!!!!!!!!! at the end it still doesn't snag as the ratio is high enough.

If this still isn't discerning enough, add a further check if you pass item 1...

2. Count numbers of consecutive A-Za-z characters in the string - work out the average length of these 'words' - if the average is too short then it is probably spam.

These can be done in RegEx reasonably easily - If you want more sophistication then you have to use something written by someone else that has much more developed statistical methods (or start reading lexographical university papers that are beyond me!)

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of thought I was looking for.